# How to automate IE/Firefox to download some files from a https: website with Javascript links?

Tags: browser, automation, webbrowser-control, javascript

Some of my users download several pdf files from an internet website regularly. They'd like to automate the process to save a few minutes every day, and most importantly, to minimize errors.

I tried [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) but failed as mechanize does not process javascripts. Since the download links in the remote site are all triggered by javescript, I am looking for solutions to automate the browser itself. Any recommendations?

- https remote server
- login and search are FORM POST
- file download link are JavaScripts
- on win32
- IE or Firefox

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Comment: I want to add to this answer and say that Watir allows you to customize browser profiles so they automatically download files without promting the user. Example: profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'text/csv,application/pdf' source:http://watir.com/guides/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of extension, such as an ActiveX or java applet. It would be [a security venerability if a web site can force the browser to download file without the user's consent](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2008/051608-apple-dismisses-safari-download.html?fsrc=rss-security).